# Function with different return type based on the string representation of the type as argument

Tags: c++, types, dependent-type

I need to create a function in C++ that returns a result with different type based on a string argument it gets, which represents this type (on the current machine that the code runs). For example, a call like this:

```
f("int", ...)
```

should return a value of type `int`, whereas the following call:

```
f("float", ...)
```

should return a value of type `float`.

I would like to avoid any kind of exhaustive switches etc, because my goal is for this process to be automated: without prior knowledge, if `f` is given a string that corresponds to an existing type, it will return a value of that type. I am solely interested on primitive C++ types.

I am starting to believe that this is not even possible. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You're asking for a very complex/powerful feature of a type system known as "dependent types", that even languages like Haskell can't really do well. I don't see much hope that there will be a way to do it.

Comment: Have you considered using template functions?

Comment: @NutCracker Wouldn't that require you to use `f<int>(...)` instead of `f("int", ...)`?

Comment: @NutCracker template functions are not "powerful" enough for what I need, given that the string representation of the type will be runtime-dependent.

Comment: It's impossible. The parameter may or may not be determined at runtime, but the return type must be known at compile time. What do you need this for?

Comment: *I need to create a function in C++ that returns a result with different type based on a string argument it gets* -- This is getting close to an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Have you looked at `std::any`?

Comment: How would you use such a function?

Comment: Types of expressions must be known at compile-time

Answer (score 2):

> I need to create a function in C++ that returns a result with different type based on a string argument it gets

You cannot. A function always return an object of one type (or reference or `void`), which cannot depend on arguments. If you try to write a call to such function and use the return value, you'll see why this fundamentally cannot work in a statically typed language:

```
const char* type = get_some_type();
??? variable = f(type);
```

What type would use use in place of `???`? You can't use `float` because the input and thus return type might be `"int"` in this hypothetical language. You cannot use `int` either because the return type might `float`. `auto` also cannot help because it deduces the type from the initialiser. It is not possible to deduce a type from something that is unknown.

Overloads or template specialisations could have different return types between each other, but overload resolution occurs at compile time and thus cannot depend on runtime values such as strings.

---

What you could do is return a tagged union such as `std::variant` of potential return types. But you do need to write each case explicitly unless you want to use meta programming outside of the language. This explicit repetition may become unnecessary in future if appropriate reflection features are introduced to the language.

Comment: @Paul Sanders notes in the question that `std::any` may be a potential solution. While generally I agree with your answer, I'm curious to see that consideration (especially in the software engineering context) with your answer.

Comment: @jhill515 Given that OP is interested in limited set of types (fundamental types), I don't see a reason to suggest `std::any`.