# How to convert a string or char* input to a data type in C++

Tags: c++, function, syntax

In C++ I'm looking for a way to write a function that accepts two inputs:

char* typeName, int L

based on the typeName variable I will declare an array,

so if typeName is "int" I will declare and array of int in size L and if typeName is float I will declare an array of floats and so on...

And also I would like to be able to know when an invalid typeName was inputted and throw an exception.

Is there a more elegant way of doing so then if else statements ?

Comment: What about using a template instead of a string parameter ? And create a concept to constrain the type.

Comment: If you are thinking about doing this at runtime, then no. [Function with different return type based on the string representation of the type as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708478/function-with-different-return-type-based-on-the-string-representation-of-the-ty)

Comment: When people wish to get a type from a string (and thus try to mix runtime and compile-time things), it's a huge red flag for an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need to get a type from a string ? What is the **actual** problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: Return type of a function cannot depend of its value argument, so you cannot have `std::array<int, 42> a = foo("int", 42); std::array<float, 4> a = foo("float", 4);`.

Comment: True, but [you can have `std::array a = foo<int, 42>();`](https://godbolt.org/z/vnYx91qf7) instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 OP doesnt actually say the want to return the array. They only say they want to declare it. Though, I suppose you guess right

Comment: In first place I'd join @Fareanor, has a pretty strong smell of a XY-problem. Sole use case for needing something like that would be if you wanted to allow selecting the type operating on via command line parameter or configuration file – still I'd scrutinise once more if that's really the way to go. If so, then a `std::variant` of different `std::vector`s might help you out. Active variant member selected upon string value, vector's size via numerical parameter.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Actually the same applies for the type of variables as well, so not much of a difference...

Comment: There was no specific problem I was trying to solve I was just being curios if there is an elegant way of doing so like more high level languages out there :) @Fareanor

Comment: @Qasdew Have quite some doubt that inventing up a problem for which no use case exists is of much value... So you might first think about what kind of problem you *might* want to solve that way – and then see if this approach is suitable for at all or if there are better ways.

Comment: I suppose you were thinking of languages like eg python where you can write `x = foo()` and `foo` can return objects of different type. This has no direct equivalent in C++. Different languages are differnt ;). Different langauges have different solution to the same problems. What is natural in python, because of its dynamic type system, requires more careful analysis of the problem in C++ (and the reverse is true as well, there are things in C++ that you need not put much brain into, while they require some thought in other languages).

Comment: C++ fundamentally doesn't work that way. (return) types must be known at compile time and cannot be determined or changed at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you write sounds like this:

```
void foo(std::string t, int L) {
     if (t == "int") {
           std::vector<int> vect(L);
     } else if (t == "float") {
           std::vector<float> vect(L);
     } else {
           // handle wrong type somehow
     }
}
```

However, this isnt very useful. Anything you want to do with one of the vectors has to happen within the respective branch. Note that I used `std::string` rather than `char*`, and `std::vector` instead of raw arrays, because thats the types you should use for strings and dynamically sized array. This wont change much about the question though.

Lets say you can choose at compile time already what type of array to use, then you can do this:

```
 template <typename T,int L>
 auto foo() {
      return std::array<T,L>();
 }
```

Now, because `foo` is a template, and choosing a different type to instantiate it will result in a separate function, there are no arrays of different types in one function. `foo<int>()` can return an array of integers and `foo<float>` can return an array of floats. Because, array sizes must be compile time constants, I made `L` a tempalte argument too.

```
 std::array<int,42> arrayi = foo<int,42>();
 std::array<float,42> arrayf = foo<float,42>();
```

---

On the other hand, there is no out-of-the box mapping between a runtime value and a type. The return type of a function is part of the function declaration. If you declare a variable you must choose what type it should be. That doesn't mean that C++ cannot do this at all. A pointer to a base class can point to instances of any type that derives from the base for example. Arrays of elements of different type have no common base though. Another way of type erasure is `std::variant` or `std::any`. Its a too broad topic to go into details. The solution to choose depends on the concrete problem at hand.

Comment: @Fareanor This doesn't answer the OPs question but is more of a qualitative judgement on the OPs problem. Dynamic dispatch should never be your first choice, but it does have some very important uses.

Comment: @SargeATM When something is not useful or bad practice, of course an answer is expected to mention it. But the answer doesn't end after the "judgement" paragraph. If you read it until the end, you'll see that it actually answers the question. But thanks for the feedback !

Comment: @Fareanor his question is how can he select code to execute based on the contents of typeName (or dispatch dynamically on typeName) without using an if/elseif chain. I don't see how this answers that question. Instead he changes the question with an assumption, "Lets say you can choose at compile time already what type of array to use", and then proceeds to answer his own version of the question.

Comment: @SargeATM It answers the question exactly in mentioning that you can't avoid the if/else dispatch if you stick with a string argument (with the limitation that you cannot, for example define the return value based on the string argument), but that you can either do it at compile-time (with templates) or with polymorphism (look at the last paragraph). So yes, for me it definitely answers the question. No point of arguing furthermore :)

Comment: @Fareanor, except that you can use a map to dispatch. So the answer is in effect wrong.

Comment: Well actually, I'm the one that extrapolated the _"can't avoid if/else"_ part. The answer didn't say this. Anyway, my point is that you should read an answer in its entirety before making such claims :)

Comment: @SargeATM sorry I cannot follow, what in the answer is wrong?

Comment: @Fareanor fair enough I should have read  
463035818_is_not_an_ai's answer in it's entirety instead of skimming it. In hindsight, I was being pedantic in my downvote. I will remove it. I can see the value in an answer that highlights why compile-time dispatch is probably what you really want.

Answer (score -1):

#### Dynamic Dispatch on a String

There are two basic methods that I know of:

- if statements
- call specific handler functions through a map of string to function pointers/functors

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Data
{
public:
    int size = 0;

    int* IntArray = nullptr;
    float* FloatArray = nullptr;
    //...
};

void HandleInt(Data& data, int L)
{
    data.size = L;
    data.IntArray = new int[L]();
}

void HandleFloat(Data& data, int L)
{
    data.size = L;
    data.FloatArray = new float[L]();
}

Data DynamicDispatchUsingIfs(char* typeName, int L)
{
    Data results{};

    if (strcmp(typeName, "int"))
    {
        HandleInt(results, L);
    }
    else if (strcmp(typeName, "float"))
    {
        HandleFloat(results, L);
    }
    else
    {
        //Handle error
    }

    return results;
}

Data DynamicDispatchUsingMap(char* typeName, int L)
{
    Data results{};
    typedef void (*Handler)(Data&, int);
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Handler> dispatchTable = {
        {"int", HandleInt},
        {"float", HandleFloat}
    };

    auto entry = dispatchTable.find(typeName);
    if (entry != dispatchTable.end())
    {
        Handler handler = entry->second;
        handler(results, L);
    }
    else
    {
        //Handle error
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: @Fareanor The `DynamicDispatchUsingMap` function only has an if/else for error handling which he also requested.

Comment: I wasn't talking about those if/else. I removed my comment because the scrollbar didn't show me your _UsingMap_ function.

Comment: A possible reason may be because your `Data` structure declare one member for each possible call when only one is actually in use, which is quite dirty. Another reason would be for the use of raw pointers when `std::array` exists. Another one would be because OP wants **one** function to _declare_ a variable not to have as many functions ("handlers") for as many possible types, etc... But I'm not the downvoter so I can't tell.

Comment: fwiw, discussing downvotes usually ends only in spam and more misunderstanding than there was initially (see comments on my answer ;). Please consider this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not and thatif the voter did not already put a comment, unlikely they will do now. I for myself, try to never reveal that I was the downvoter even if I am convinced my vote is completely justified.

Comment: comments are for feedback on the contents not on the votes ;)

Comment: you are basically reimplementing what `std::variant` and related machinery can do already. The same can be done with much less boilerplate

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm not familiar with variant. I tend to write mostly orthodox C++ instead of modern.